# PayPal error in iOS - This app not using a supported version of the PayPal library

Tags: objective-c, ios, paypal, sandbox

Yesterday my app with PayPal sandbox integration was working just fine and today its not working. Just downloaded the latest library from PayPal version 1.6 but the sample app from PayPal says this error too.
Anyone with any idea what is wrong? Is it something from PayPal or from iOS end? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! I updated to Mac OS X 10.7.4 and installed Xcode 4.5 and then integrated the new PayPal library 1.6 and it worked. I believe PayPal developers must be updating there sdk for iOS 6. The library now supports iOS 4.3 to iOS 6.